# I can't load images to my pygame program

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and was copying a simple tutorial. i'm using python 3.4.2. but i'm running into several issues. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))

class Game(object):
    def main(self,screen):
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
        image_x=320
        image_y=240

    while True:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key== pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
        image_x+=10

        screen.fill((200,200,200))
        screen.blit(image,(320,240))
        screen.blit(image,(image_x,image_y))
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
Game().main(screen)
```

first problem is that i get an error stating "Couldn't open player.png" i have this image saved within the same folder as my .py game program. secondly when i try to exit the game, the pygame window freezes and stops responding.

Comment: If you do `pygame.image.get_extended()` what does it return?

Comment: where do i put that into the script?

Comment: Make a new script with just 2 lines: `import pygame` 2nd line: `pygame.image.get_extended()`

Comment: Make the second line `print(pygame.image.get_extended())`

Comment: This leads me to believe that python can't find the png file.  Are you sure it's in the right place?  Can you add the following code to your script?  Near the imports: `import os` and then right before you load the image do: `os.listdir('.')`

Comment: Also, the 2nd and third lines look redundant.  Make sure your tabbing is correct after the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line.

Comment: yea tutorial got a little confusing, i fixed the redunduncies and the tabbing was just my bad typing it into the question box. i imported os and added the code u showed but nothing changed

Comment: I guess you need to print the listdir like so: `print(os.listdir('.'))`

Comment: i figured, so i tried both and still nothing happened

Comment: would you like to move this to a chat?

Comment: Ya, please do.  Makes more sense

Comment: ah, i can't not enough reputation yet, i'm new on here

Comment: but i got that to work. it showed me all the .py files i've made in a folder. within this folder i have a folder which has my game program and picture. so it gave me the files outside of this folder

Comment: okay, i guessed that those files is where it has been looking so i moved the image there and that worked!

Comment: If the picture is in a subfolder, you need to add the path to the load command, something like this: `image = pygame.image.load('subfolder' + os.sep + 'player.png').convert()`

Comment: why is it like that? and is there a way to change where it is looking?

Comment: You could just use a backslash or `/` depending on your OS, but `os.sep` is cross platform.

Comment: Note that you'll need to keep the `import os` line to use `os.sep`

Comment: okay i changed the path it works now. now importing os for all that, will that slow down the program any mentionable amount?

Comment: Not really.  The `import os` call won't even take a millisecond.

Comment: okay, thankyou very much for taking this time for my question. really helped me understand better how some of this works!

Comment: no problem, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems after a little debugging that the image file was actually in a subfolder.  In order to load the image, you'll need to provide a more exact path to the file by changing this line

```
image = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert()
```

like so:

```
image = pygame.image.load('subfolder' + os.sep + 'player.png').convert()
```

Don't forget to add an `import os` line to the top of your file, in order to use the `os.sep` command, which makes directory separators cross platform.